# Какие здесь нужны знаки препинания?

Tags: приложение

Дети спрятались в доме (?) каменной пещере (?) от ливня с грозой.

Comment: Хотелось б иметь больше информации: 1) почему каменная пещера стала домом; б) каково происхождение предложения.

Comment: В доме,  а может быть - пещере? От ливня, а может - от грозы? Уточните или дайте контекст.

Comment: Дети играют, и в этой игре дом для них - каменная пещера. Ливень в данном случае сопровождается грозой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дети спрятались в доме - каменной пещере  от ливня с грозой.

Обособление с помощью одного тире (второе тире опускается) при тесной связи приложения и определяемого слова, в этом случае произношение без паузы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Vera!

Answer (score 2):

Дети спрятались в домике — каменной пещере от ливня и грозы. Почему домик, а не дом, понятно. И перед словом с начальными согласными лучше не увеличивать число согласных.

Comment: В данном случае дети спрятались от ливня с грозой не в игрушечном, а в настоящем (большом) доме - каменной пещере. Спасибо за помощь, shampar!